Can we get a connection on the principal bundle from a connection on the associated vector bundle?
Assume $G$ is a Lie group, $P \to M$ is a smooth principal $G$-bundle, and $\rho \colon G \to GL(V)$ is a smooth representation of $G$. We can define a connection on the associated vector bundle $E := P \times_{\rho} V$ from a connection 1-form $\omega \in \Omega^1(P, Lie(G))$ on $P$ as follows
\begin{equation}
\nabla s = \nabla [u, v] := [u, dv + \rho_{\ast}(u^{\ast}\omega)v],
\end{equation}
where $u$ is a local section of $P$ on $U \subset M$ and $v \colon U \to V$.
My question : Is there any way to do the reverse of the above one ? Namely, can we construct a connection $\omega$ on $P$ when given a connection $\nabla$ on associated vector bundle $E$ ?
I think the answer is No in general.
But I trust under some appropriate assumption (for connection $\nabla$ or representation $\rho$), we can do that.
Thank you.

You can get a connection on the frame bundle of the vector bundle. But  the problem is that it might not arise from a connection on a principal subbundle of the frame bundle.That depends on the holonomy of the connection.

@Ben McKay Yes. My question is not only the case of a subbundle of the frame bundle. Is the restriction only holonomy ? Could you tell me more details or some reference ?
